How to synchronize a JSRuntime call in Blazor WASM
I am developing a Blazor WASM app that needs to interact with an IndexedDB (the mock code below shows what I would like if it was synchronous).  Since JSRuntime calls are async, I'm forced to use inelegant callback logic after GetData completes, even though there's virtually no advantage to the async processing because code Blocks 2 & 4 need the data before proceeding and the database access delays are miniscule.  I've been looking for various ways to make the database access synchronous (either the JSRuntime call or the calls to GetData),but so far  no luck. I'm far from proficient in async logic, so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Also, I'm open to using a different DBMS that doesn't require JS.  The database is not very complicated.
Thanks for any guidance you can provide.
private void Method1()
{
// Block 1: some code
GetData(key1);
// Block 2: some code
}

private void Method2()
{
// Block 3: some code
GetData(key2);
// Block 4: some code
}

private async Task<MyData> GetData(int key)
{
MyData myData = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<MyData>("MyJS_Get", key);
return myData;
}

